# Hyperas grid search with a network with multiple inputs

Tags: python-2.7, keras, grid-search

I currently having problems using [hyperas](https://github.com/maxpumperla/hyperas) optimiser on my network with multiple inputs..

This is how I've implemented it:

```
def data():
    X_train, Y_train = next(train_generator())
    X_test, Y_test = next(test_generator())

    datagen = ImageDataGenerator()
    train_list = []
    for input in X_train:
        train_list.append(datagen.fit(input))

    return datagen, train_list, Y_train, X_test, Y_test
```

I am using a data_generator as all the data can't be contained in RAM.

Based on the [data example](https://github.com/maxpumperla/hyperas/blob/master/examples/cifar_generator_cnn.py) they made, I made this:

```
def fws(datagen, X_train, Y_train, X_test, Y_test):
    # Input shape: (batch_size,40,45,3)
    # Output shape: (1,15,50)
    # Number of units in conv_feature_map = splitd
    filter_size = 8
    pooling_size = 28
    stride_step = 2
    pool_splits = ((splits - pooling_size)+1)/2
    temp_list = []
    sun_temp_list = []
    conv_featur_map = []
    pool_feature_map = []
    print "Printing shapes"

    list_of_input = [Input(shape = (window_height,total_frames_with_deltas,3)) for i in range(splits)]

    # Convolution
    shared_conv = Conv2D(filters = 150, kernel_size = (filter_size,45), activation='relu')
    for i in range(splits):
        conv_featur_map.append(shared_conv(list_of_input[i]))

    # Pooling
    input = Concatenate()(conv_featur_map)
    input = Reshape((splits,-1))(input)
    pooled = MaxPooling1D(pool_size = pooling_size, strides = stride_step)(input)

    # fc
    dense1 = Dense(units = 1000, activation = 'relu',    name = "dense_1")(pooled)
    dense2 = Dense(units = 1000, activation = 'relu',    name = "dense_2")(dense1)
    dense3 = Dense(units = 50 , activation = 'softmax', name = "dense_3")(dense2)

    model = Model(inputs = list_of_input , outputs = dense3)
    sgd = keras.optimizers.SGD(lr = {{uniform(0, 1)}}, decay = {{uniform(0, 1)}}, momentum = {{uniform(0, 1)}}, nesterov = True)
    model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer=sgd , metrics = [metrics.categorical_accuracy])

    hist_current = model.fit_generator(datagen.flow(X_train, Y_train),
                        steps_per_epoch=32,
                        epochs = 1000,
                        verbose = 1,
                        validation_data = (X_test, Y_test),
                        validation_steps=32,
                        pickle_safe = True,
                        workers = 4)

    score, acc = model.evaluate(X_test, Y_test, verbose=0)

    return {'loss': -acc, 'status': STATUS_OK, 'model': model}
```

Special to this network is that it takes in multiple inputs. I could have made it only take in one input and use a lambda layer to split it, but since the splitting is pretty tedious, I decided to store it split, and feed it in split, hence creating 33 inputs. Otherwise the network is pretty standard.

(Visualization of the network)

[image]

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    datagen, X_train, Y_train, X_test, Y_test = data()

    best_run, best_model = optim.minimize(model=fws,
                                          data=data,
                                          algo=tpe.suggest,
                                          max_evals=5,
                                          trials=Trials())

    print("Evalutation of best performing model:")
    print(best_model.evaluate(X_test, Y_test))
```

This is where I begin optimizing, and also where I am getting an error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "keras_cnn_phoneme_original_fit_generator_hyperas.py", line 211, in <module>
    trials=Trials())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/hyperas/optim.py", line 43, in minimize
    notebook_name=notebook_name, verbose=verbose)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/hyperas/optim.py", line 63, in base_minimizer
    model_str = get_hyperopt_model_string(model, data,functions,notebook_name, verbose, stack)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/hyperas/optim.py", line 130, in get_hyperopt_model_string
    imports = extract_imports(cleaned_source, verbose)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/hyperas/utils.py", line 44, in extract_imports
    import_parser.visit(tree)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ast.py", line 241, in visit
    return visitor(node)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ast.py", line 249, in generic_visit
    self.visit(item)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ast.py", line 241, in visit
    return visitor(node)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/hyperas/utils.py", line 14, in visit_Import
    if (self._import_asnames(node.names)!=''):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/hyperas/utils.py", line 36, in _import_asnames
    return ''.join(asname)
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, NoneType found
```

I am not sure how should interpret this error. Is this an implementation error or an error in the library? I don't know...

A minimal working example:

```
import numpy as np
import re
from keras.utils import np_utils
from keras import metrics
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.optimizers import SGD
import scipy
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Activation, Lambda, Reshape,Flatten
from keras.layers import Conv1D,Conv2D,MaxPooling2D, MaxPooling1D, Reshape
#from keras.utils.visualize_util import plot
from keras.utils import np_utils
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Input, Dense
from keras.layers import Dropout
from keras import backend as K
from keras.layers.merge import Concatenate
from keras.models import load_model
from keras.utils import plot_model
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
import math
import random
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
import tensorflow as tf
from hyperopt import Trials, STATUS_OK, tpe
from hyperas import optim
from hyperas.distributions import uniform

def train_generator():
    while True:
        train_input = np.random.randint(100,size=(1,33,8,45,3))
        train_input_list = np.split(train_input,33,axis=1)

        for i in range(len(train_input_list)):
            train_input_list[i] = train_input_list[i].reshape(1,8,45,3)

        train_output = np.random.randint(100,size=(1,3,50))
        yield (train_input_list, train_output)

def test_generator():
    while True:
        test_input = np.random.randint(100,size=(1,33,8,45,3))
        test_input_list = np.split(test_input,33,axis=1)

        for i in range(len(test_input_list)):
            test_input_list[i] = test_input_list[i].reshape(1,8,45,3)

        test_output = np.random.randint(100,size=(1,3,50))

        yield (test_input_list, test_output)

def data():
    X_train, Y_train = next(train_generator())
    X_test, Y_test = next(test_generator())

    datagen = ImageDataGenerator()
    train_list = []
    for input in X_train:
        train_list.append(datagen.fit(input))

    return datagen, train_list, Y_train, X_test, Y_test

def fws(datagen, X_train, Y_train, X_test, Y_test):
    # Input shape: (batch_size,40,45,3)
    # Output shape: (1,15,50)
    # Number of units in conv_feature_map = splitd
    filter_size = 8
    pooling_size = 28
    stride_step = 2
    pool_splits = ((splits - pooling_size)+1)/2
    temp_list = []
    sun_temp_list = []
    conv_featur_map = []
    pool_feature_map = []
    print "Printing shapes"

    list_of_input = [Input(shape = (8,45,3)) for i in range(33)]

    # Convolution
    shared_conv = Conv2D(filters = 150, kernel_size = (filter_size,45), activation='relu')
    for i in range(splits):
        conv_featur_map.append(shared_conv(list_of_input[i]))

    # Pooling
    input = Concatenate()(conv_featur_map)
    input = Reshape((splits,-1))(input)
    pooled = MaxPooling1D(pool_size = pooling_size, strides = stride_step)(input)

    #reshape = Reshape((3,-1))(pooled)

    #fc
    dense1 = Dense(units = 1000, activation = 'relu',    name = "dense_1")(pooled)
    dense2 = Dense(units = 1000, activation = 'relu',    name = "dense_2")(dense1)
    dense3 = Dense(units = 50 , activation = 'softmax', name = "dense_3")(dense2)


    model = Model(inputs = list_of_input , outputs = dense3)
    sgd = keras.optimizers.SGD(lr = {{uniform(0, 1)}}, decay = {{uniform(0, 1)}}, momentum = {{uniform(0, 1)}}, nesterov = True)
    model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer=sgd , metrics = [metrics.categorical_accuracy])

    hist_current = model.fit_generator(datagen.flow(X_train, Y_train),
                        steps_per_epoch=32,
                        epochs = 1000,
                        verbose = 1,
                        validation_data = (X_test, Y_test),
                        validation_steps=32,
                        pickle_safe = True,
                        workers = 4)

    score, acc = model.evaluate(X_test, Y_test, verbose=0)

    return {'loss': -acc, 'status': STATUS_OK, 'model': model}

if __name__ == '__main__':

    datagen, X_train, Y_train, X_test, Y_test = data()

    best_run, best_model = optim.minimize(model=fws,
                                          data=data,
                                          algo=tpe.suggest,
                                          max_evals=5,
                                          trials=Trials())

    print("Evalutation of best performing model:")
    print(best_model.evaluate(X_test, Y_test))
```

Comment: Your minimal working example has multiple issues. `splits` not defined, many variables assigned but never used. Can you check it once?

Comment: The error message "TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, NoneType found" sounds like the first element of your input sequence was not read properly. First step might be to check your data (missing value?), and check how you read your data in.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is related to the `data` function.

Here:

```
datagen, X_train, Y_train, X_test, Y_test = data()
```

`X_train` corresponds to `train_list`, which is generated by:

```
datagen = ImageDataGenerator()
train_list = []
for input in X_train:
    train_list.append(datagen.fit(input))
```

So `train_list` is not an array. It is just a list full of what `datagen.fit` returns, which is `None`.